# Is options ignoreExpiration still valid in node-jose?

Tags: jose, node-jose

In `jsonwebtoken`, the option `ignoreExpiration` can be used as below for HS256:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const decoded = await jwt.verify(jwt_token, process.env.jwtPrivateKey,
    {ignoreExpiration: true});
```

Now the app is migrating to `node-jose 2.0.9`. Is `ignoreExpiration` still a valid option in `node-jose` as well?

```
const jose = require('node-jose');
const decoded = await jose.JWT.createVerify(pubkey, {ignoreExpiration: true,
    algorithms: ['EdDSA']}).verify(jwt_token); //Is ignoreExpiration valid here?
```

Comment: I think you can use clockTolerance and give some tolerance time
please check, https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/interfaces/types.JWTClaimVerificationOptions.md#clocktolerance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-jose` is for general JOSE constructs, it does not support the JWT Claim Set validations like `exp`, `iat`, `iss`, `aud`, etc.

Therefore `ignoreExpiration` is not a valid option for any of the `node-jose` APIs.

You can of course refer to `node-jose` documentation to see there's no mention of any such option.

Comment: jose supports validation. See [`jose.jwtVerify()`](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/functions/jwt_verify.jwtVerify.md)

Answer (score 2):

`jose.JWTVerifyOptions` has a `currentDate` parameter. It defaults to `Date.now()` but you can specify a date earlier than the issue date of the token to ensure verification won't fail based on expiration time. This has the same effect as jsonwebtoken's `ignoreExpiration: true`.

For example:

```js
jose.jwtVerify(jwt, key, { currentDate: new Date(0) });
```

See the [JWTVerifyOptions documentation](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/interfaces/jwt_verify.JWTVerifyOptions.md#currentdate).